# Previous state rendering in Chat thread React JS

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have created a form which has two dropdowns when I select both of them and click on Add Story Button then a chat thread is added.

The **problem** is when I select New Intent Name and New Action Name from dropdown then the previous Action Name also gets added I don't want like that what I want is

**Problem:-**
One Intent Name can Have multiple Actions But not duplicate actions

I think I am not setting or mapping the state variable properly, please guide me as of where am I going wrong

While I am able to manage the 1st point I want help with the below two
[image: Duplicate Actions][image: Previous Actions]

My Code

```
        import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  Form,
  Input,
  Button,
  Select,
  Card,
  Typography,
  notification,
} from "antd";
import { Layout } from "antd";
const { Header, Footer, Content } = Layout;
const { Text } = Typography;
const { Option } = Select;
const CreateStory = () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const [storyValue, setStoryValue] = useState("")
  const [intentName, setIntentName] = useState([])
  const [actionName, setActionName] = useState([])
  const [valueIntent, setValueIntent] = useState("")
  const [valueAction, setValueAction] = useState("")
  const [results,setResults] = useState([])
  const [uniqueResults,setUniqueResults] = useState([])

  const storyInputValue = (e) => {
    setStoryValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const onFinish = (values) => {
    // console.log("Success:", values);
  };

  const onFinishFailed = (errorInfo: any) => {
    console.log("Failed:", errorInfo);
  };

  const SelectIntentName = (valueIntent) => {
    setValueIntent(valueIntent)
    console.log(valueIntent)
  };

  const SelectActionName = (valueAction) => {
    // console.log(valueAction)
    setValueAction(valueAction);
    setActionName(prev => [...prev,valueAction])
  };
  // Error Notification
  const openNotificationWithIcon = (type) => {
    notification[type]({
      message: "intent name cannot be empty",
    });
  };

  const addStory = () => {
    // setActionName(prev => [...prev,valueAction])
    results.push({
      intent_name: valueIntent,
      // if valueAction is already present then don't push it into the array
      actions: [...new Set(actionName)]
    })
     const removedDup = ([...new Map(results.map((item, key) => [item["intent_name"], item])).values()])
    // setUniqueResults(prev => removedDup)
    setUniqueResults(removedDup)
  }
  console.log(uniqueResults)

  
  return (
    <div className="csi-create-story-component-page-0103CS">
      <Card
        title="Create Story"
        className="csi-create-story-screen-card-0104SC"
        size="small"
      >
        <Form
          onFinish={onFinish}
          onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
          layout="vertical"
        >
          <Form.Item
            label="Story Name"
            name="Story Name"
            rules={[
              { required: true, message: "Please input your story name!" },
            ]}
          >
            <Input
              value={storyValue}
              onChange={storyInputValue}
              placeholder="Enter story name"
            />
          </Form.Item>
          <div className="csi-action-intent-box-grid-column-0126">
            <Form.Item
              label="Intent Name"
              name="Intent Name"
              rules={[
                { required: true, message: "Please select your intent name!" },
              ]}
            >
              <Select
                placeholder="Select a option"
                allowClear
                showSearch
                onSelect={SelectIntentName}
              >
                <Option value="intent_name_1">intent_name_1</Option>
                <Option value="intent_name_2">intent_name_2</Option>
                <Option value="intent_name_3">intent_name_3</Option>
              </Select>
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item
              label="Action Name"
              name="Action Name"
              rules={[
                { required: true, message: "Please select your action name!" },
              ]}
            >
              <Select
                placeholder="Select a option"
                allowClear
                showSearch
                onSelect={SelectActionName}
              >
                <Option value="action_name_1">action_name_1</Option>
                <Option value="action_name_2">action_name_2</Option>
                <Option value="action_name_3">action_name_3</Option>
              </Select>
            </Form.Item>
          </div>
          <Form.Item>
            <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" onClick={addStory}>
              ADD STORY
            </Button>
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      </Card>
      <div>
        <Layout className="csi-created-story-list-screen-card-0105SLS">
          <Header>{storyValue}</Header>
          <Content className="csi-intent-action-content-layout-0353IA">
          <div
              className="csi-created-intent-action-parent-box-0237IA"
            >
            {uniqueResults.map((uniqueResult,index) => {
              return(
                <div key={index}>
                  <div className="csi-intent-name-left-box">
                    <span className="csi-intent-text-com-0245I">
                      <span className="csi-INTENT-text">Intent</span>
                      <Text>{uniqueResult.intent_name}</Text>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <div className="csi-action-name-right-box">
                        <span className="csi-action-text-com-0246A">
                          <span className="csi-ACTION-text">Action</span>
                          <Text>{uniqueResult.actions[index]}</Text>
                        </span>
                  </div>
               </div>
              )
            })}
            </div>
            {/* <div
              className="csi-created-intent-action-parent-box-0237IA"
            >
              {intentName.map((intentName, index) => {
                return (
                    <>
                  <div className="csi-intent-name-left-box" key={index}>
                    <span className="csi-intent-text-com-0245I">
                      <span className="csi-INTENT-text">Intent</span>
                      <Text>{intentName}</Text>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  {actionName.map((actionName, index) => {
                    return (
                      <div className="csi-action-name-right-box" key={Math.random().toString()}>
                        <span className="csi-action-text-com-0246A">
                          <span className="csi-ACTION-text">Action</span>
                          <Text>{actionName}</Text>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                    );
                  })}
                  </>
                )
              })}

              {actionName.map((actionName, index) => {
                return (
                  <div className="csi-action-name-right-box" key={index}>
                    <span className="csi-action-text-com-0246A">
                      <span className="csi-ACTION-text">Action</span>
                      <Text>{actionName}</Text>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div> */}
          </Content>
          <Footer className="csi-footer-submit-button-for-intent-action-0357">
            <Button type="primary">Submit</Button>
          </Footer>
        </Layout>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default CreateStory;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely because of index in key prop. React doesn't know what you want to render there.

Don't use index as key if you're going to change order of items

Comment: I set my key as key = {Math.random().toString()} but it didn't work

Comment: So best approach it is using `id`, or somehow provide this uniq value. You even can use compbination of name and index: `${intentName}-${index}`, maybe it will be work in your case

Comment: No it didn't work

Comment: try uniq value in this way

Comment: I tried I guess something else is the issue maybe I am not mapping correctly, because I keep getting previous action name when I add new intent that's not what I want

Answer (score 0):

The main issue relies with your implementation. You can not handle it with two array of strings.
My opinion -
Use a result array which will have items as object -

```
{
  "intent_name": "",
  "actions": [] //array of string
}
```

Whenever **Add Story** button is clicked give an entry to this result array. condition should be like - if intent_name already exist then -> check if object.actions already have entry -> if not then give entry.

and loop through this result array to show the intent action list.

You can also use id instead of name in terms of uniqueness.

Comment: So basically like this array I have to create like this ?? result = [{
  "intent_name": "",
  "actions": [] //array of string
}]

Comment: How can I check if object.actions already have an entry since actions is an array ??

Comment: loop through the array and check.